# Prove diagonalizabilty from a polynomial in $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

Suppose that $T^3 = 3T^2 - 2T$. Prove that T is diagonalizable.

I have proved that T is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial of T has no repeated roots.

$$T^3 - 3T^2 +2T = T(T^2-3T+2 ) = T( T-1)(T-2) $$ this polynomial has no repeated roots i would like to conclude that the minimal polynomial of $T$ cannot have any repeated roots? but im not sure theirs correlation between this polynomial and the minimal one? i think its just a notation thing cause my textbook and prof use diffrent notation for everything so im not really sure what $T^3 = 3T^2 - 2T$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $T$ divided $x(x-1)(x-2)$ (since $T$ is a root of this polynomial) and all factors of this polynomial ($1$, $x$, $x-1$, $x-2$, $x(x-1)$, $x(x-2)$, $(x-1)(x-2)$, and $x(x-1)(x-2)$) have distinct roots.

Comment: Thank you the since T is a root of this polynomial clarified my question

Comment: @Faust If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: it takes 10 minutes till you can accept the answer so i had to wait.